Is the partial order of all equations in the signature of magmas a lattice?
$\newcommand\Eq{\mathrm{Eq}}$I asked this question on math stack exchange, here, but there were no comments or answers. So, I am asking it here on mathoverflow. Consider the signature of a single binary operation $*$, and consider the set $\Eq$ of all equations in that signature. I can define a preorder $\geq$ on $\Eq$ by stipulating that $E \geq E'$ precisely when $E$ implies $E'$. I can now consider the partial order obtained by quotienting out the preorder by its standard equivalence relation. My question is, is this partial order a lattice? If not, is it at least a join semilattice or a meet semilattice? If not even that, is it still at least the case that for every pair of elements, either the pair has a least upper bound or a greatest lower bound? I would be very interested to be given a pair of equations such that they have neither a least upper bound nor a greatest lower bound.

Do the associative law and the commutative law have a least upper bound and/or a greatest lower bound in your partial order?

@bof I don't know, but if it has neither, that would answer my question.

You have least and greatest elements $x=x$ and $x=y$, so the question is whether two elements can have multiple incomparable common maximal lower / minimal upper bounds.

In general, $p(\vec{x})=q(\vec{x})$ implies $r(p(\vec{x}), q(\vec{x}), \vec{y}) = r(q(\vec{x}), p(\vec{x}), \vec{y})$. By using $r_i$ of arity four or more we can generate arbitrarily many lower bounds on a pair of equations, and in general there's no reason to suppose that these lower bounds are mutually comparable.

If this question has a negative answer, it may be possible to resolve it by looking through the implication graph produced by Terence Tao's recent equational theories project, searching for pairs of nodes without least upper bounds or greatest lower bounds. The table of implications is available through this page.

Is the partial order of all equations in the signature of magmas a lattice?
No.
If not, is it at least a join semilattice or a meet semilattice?
No.
If not even that, is it still at least the case that for every pair of elements, either the pair has a least upper bound or a greatest lower bound?
No.
I would be very interested to be given a pair of equations such that they have neither a least upper bound nor a greatest lower bound.
Let $\Sigma$ be the set of all magma identities.
Preorder $\Sigma$ by stipulating that
if $I, J\in\Sigma$, then
$I\geq J$ iff $I\vdash J$.
Assume also that $I\geq J$ is equivalent to $J\leq I$.
Let $A$ denote the Associative Law, $x(yz)=(xy)z$. Let
$C$ denote the Commutative Law, $xy=yx$. I will explain why
$A$ and $C$ do not have a meet or join in $\langle\Sigma;\leq\rangle$.
Lemma 1.
$A\wedge C$ does not exist.
Proof.
Assume instead that a greatest lower bound $A\wedge C$ exists,
and set $M=A\wedge C$. This means that $A\vdash M$, $C\vdash M$,
and, for any identity $I$, if
both $A\vdash I$ and $C\vdash I$ hold then $M\vdash I$ also holds.
Let's say that a magma term/word $t$ has weight $\geq n$
if it has $\geq n$ occurrences of variables.
Let's say that a magma identity $I: t_1=t_2$
has weight $\geq n$
if both of $t_i$ and $t_2$ have weight $\geq n$.
For both terms or identities, say that a weight is equal to $n$
if it is $\geq n$ and not $\geq n-1$.
(Write $w(t)=n$ or $w(I)=n$ to indicate this.)
Let's call a magma identity $I$ strongly regular
if, for each variable $x$, there are the same number of occurrences
of $x$ on both sides of $I$.
The associative law $A$ is strongly regular of weight $3$
and the commutative law $C$ is strongly regular of
weight $2$. It follows from the laws of equational deduction
(Theorem 14.7 of Burris-Sankappanavar) that if
$C\vdash I$, then $I$ is strongly regular and $w(I)\geq 2$,
while if $A\vdash I$, then $I$ is strongly regular and $w(I)\geq 3$.
We conclude that $M$ is strongly regular of weight at least $3$.
We argue next that the weight of the meet
$M$ cannot be $\geq 4$, hence
$w(M)=3$. To see this, observe that the magma
$\mathbf{P}=\langle \{0,1,2,3\}; \cdot\rangle$ whose operation
table is
$$
\begin{array}{|c||c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\cdot & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
\hline
\end{array}  
$$
satisfies every magma identity $t_1=t_2$
of weight at least $4$. This is because
the interpretation of any magma term of weight at
least $4$ is constant $0$.
Now, if the meet identity $M$ had weight at least $4$,
then it would hold in $\mathbf{P}$.
But $A\vdash x(yx)=x(yx)$ and
$C\vdash x(yx)=x(yx)$, so we must have
$M\vdash x(yx)=x(yx)$ if $M$ is truly the meet of $A$ and $C$.
Since $\mathbf{P}\models M$ (provided $w(M)\geq 4$) we would have
$\mathbf{P}\models x(yx)=x(yx)$. But this is false,
as one sees by substituting $x=3=y$.
This completes the proof that $w(M)=3$.
Since $w(M)=3$ and $M$ is strongly regular, we must have
that $M$ equals $t_1=t_2$ where $t_1$ and $t_2$
both involve three variables. Since
$A\vdash M$, the words $t_1$ and $t_2$
become identical if we ignore the placement of parentheses.
But since $M$ is nontrivial, $t_1$ and $t_2$
are not identical, so they must differ only in the
order of parentheses. That is,
$M$ equals $v_1(v_2v_3)=(v_1v_2)v_3$ for some variables
$v_1, v_2, v_3\in \{x,y,z\}$. Up to the renaming of variables
$M$ must be one of

 $x(xx)=(xx)x$
 $x(yx)=(xy)x$
 $x(xy)=(xx)y$
 $x(yy)=(xy)y$
 $x(yz)=(xy)z$

Only the first two choices are consequences of $C$, so we can exclude the others.
(The last three choices fail in the commutative magma with universe $\{0,1\}$ whose product
has Boolean expression $\neg x\wedge \neg y$.)
The first two identities are consequences of both $A$ and $C$,
but $x(yx)=(xy)x$ is the stronger identity,
hence it is the only viable candidate for the 
meet identity $M$.
We have reached the conclusion that the only viable candidate
for $M$ is $x(yx)=(xy)x$. This identity is
a consequence of both $A$ and $C$, but it is not their meet.
The identity
$$
((xy)z)(x(yz)) = (x(yz))((xy)z) 
$$
is also a consequence of both $A$ and $C$, yet it is not a consequence
of $x(yx)=(xy)x$. This was proved by user bof
here.
This shows that the meet of $A$ and $C$ does not exist.
\\\
Lemma 2.
$A\vee C$ does not exist.
Proof.
Assume instead that a least upper bound $A\vee C$ exists,
and set $J=A\vee C$. This means that $J\vdash A$, $J\vdash C$,
and, for any identity $I$, if
both $I\vdash A$ and $I\vdash C$ hold then $I\vdash J$.
I now define the Kinyon-McCune identity.
Let $t_n(x) = (x(x(\cdots (xx)\cdots )))$ be a right associated
product of $n-1$ variables, all equal to $x$. Let $KM_n$
be the identity
$$
((xy)z)\cdot t_n(xz) = y.
$$
Since $t_n$ is an abbreviation of a magma term, this
is a magma identity. I explain after the proof why $KM_n$
is a single magma identity that defines the variety
of abelian groups of exponent $n$ considered as magmas
with group product as the binary operation.
Let's accept this claim for now.
Since $KM_n\vdash A$ and $KM_n\vdash C$, we must have
$KM_n\vdash J$ for all $n$.
This implies that $J$ holds in every finite abelian group.
Since free commutative semigroups
are residually in the class of finite abelian groups,
it follows that $J$ holds in every
free commutative semigroup, hence in every commutative
semigroup.
On the other hand, since $J\vdash A$ and $J\vdash C$,
every model of $J$ must be a commutative semigroup.
This is enough to prove that the identity $J$
must be a single axiom
that defines the class of commutative semigroups.
But there is no such axiom, as
was proved by user bof here.
This shows that there is no identity $J$
that is the join of $A$ and $C$.
\\\

Let me say something about the Kinyon-McCune identity.
William McCune discovered that the identity
$$
((xy)z)\cdot u(xz)=y
$$
in the signature $\{\textrm{product}, u(x)\}$
defines the class of abelian groups
in which $u(x)$ must interpret as $x^{-1}$.
His result is Theorem 2 of
William W. McCune, 
Single Axioms for Groups and Abelian Groups with Various Operations

Journal of Automated Reasoning 10: 1-13, 1993.
Michael Kinyon noticed that if you choose
$u(x) = (x(x(\cdots (xx)\cdots)))$, ($n-1$ $x$'s),
then McCune's Identity
$((xy)z)\cdot u(xz)=y$
will define a variety of abelian groups
satisfying $x^{-1} = u(x) = x^{n-1}$. This shows
that $KM_n$ defines some subvariety of the variety
of abelian groups of exponent $n$ with a single identity
in the language of product alone. But since $KM_n$ holds
in any abelian group of exponent $n$, the variety
axiomatized by $KM_n$ must be the full variety of all abelian groups of exponent $n$.

This a note hosted by your homepage, with no mention of any author. Is this on purpose?

@YCor: I am the author. The answer was a bit long, so I thought it would be easier to read as a separate document. But let me edit so the reader has a choice.

Sure, thanks for the details. You might want to include your name in the document too.

(Side note: the name '$B$' is used in a couple of places where '$C$' should be, specifically in the paragraph(s) immediately after the statements of Lemmata 1 and 2. I would propose an edit but MO says that it's too small.)

@StevenStadnicki: Fixed! Thanks.

Either I'm confused or there's a typo in the definition of P. You wrote "the interpretation of any magma term of weight at least 4 is constant 0." But $(3\cdot 3)\cdot(3\cdot3)=2\cdot2=1$.

@AndreasBlass: Thanks! To respond to this, I changed the definition of $\mathbf{P}$ so that $2\cdot 2 = 0$. The new $\mathbf{P}$ still fails $x(yx)=(xy)x$, but now all products of $4$ elements are zero.
